# summernote is not working in laravel with npm

Tags: node.js, laravel, webpack, summernote

I am new in laravel. I installed npm before some days. And now I need editor in my application. So I have installed it via npm using "npm install summernote --save-dev" command. And add below lines in my app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('summernote');
require('summernote/dist/summernote.css');
require('summernote/dist/summernote.js');
require('jquery');
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content_editor').summernote();
});
```

and then compiled the assets via "npm run dev" command. But it will display 2 textarea, one that is in my html and second is summernote textarea. It is not displaying toolbars and other things. It is displaying only textarea.

Can anybody please help me to resolved this problem. I am newly learning laravel. So, I don't have deep knowledge of packages. I just want to display it without including css and js to header. I need it via webpack.

Comment: are u using webpack directly or laravel-mix?

Comment: I am using laravel-mix

Comment: If anyone have other better editor than summernote then I will change. My requirement is editor with toolbars.

Answer (score 0):

This code in app.js with Laravel 8 does work:

```js
require('./bootstrap');
require('summernote');
require('summernote/dist/summernote.css');
require('summernote/dist/summernote.js');

import $ from 'jquery';

window.$ = window.jQuery = $;



$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.summernote').summernote();
});
```

Comment: I faced Uncaught TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function this error in laravel 8.   first I loaded Jquery & then after I load summernote   `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery'); require('summernote');
    require('summernote/dist/summernote.css');
    require('summernote/dist/summernote.js');
`  but still it show error. please help me

Comment: The code I posted worked on my software, but it was two years ago so longer remeber the details; I think I have switched that software to another editor https://froala.com ... not free, but it worked without hassles.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in webpack.mix.js configuration file. It should appear something like:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
let path = require('path');

mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: { jQuery: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js') }
    }
});

// Into app.js, you require 'summernote' as always
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/javascript/summernote-and-webpack