# Integration of Summernote and jQuery in Laravel 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, summernote

So I was wanting to integrate Summernote WYSiWYG editor to my Laravel 9 project directly, that means, without using the CDN. To clarify, I am trying that **on a fresh Laravel 9 project** made by `composer create-project laravel/laravel:^9.5 laratests`. For this, I took the following steps:

1. I've executed the following command from the terminal:

```
npm i jquery summernote
```

2. I went to the file `resources/js/app.js`.
3. I put the following contents:

```
import './bootstrap';
require('summernote');
require('summernote/dist/summernote.css');
require('summernote/dist/summernote.js');

import $ from 'jquery';

window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

That was advised in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61075342/summernote-is-not-working-in-laravel-with-npm).
4. I put the following in my view file's head before the closing tag:

```
@vite(['resources/js/app.js'])
```

5. I put the following in my view file's body (which should work [according to Summernote docs](https://summernote.org/getting-started/#without-bootstrap-lite)):

```
<div id="summernote">Hello Summernote</div>
```

6. I put the following right before the closing body tag in my view file:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.summernote').summernote();
    });
</script>
```

7. I did `npm run build`, and then `php artisan serve` to open the page.

I expected this to work, but instead, the console gave me the following errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>  http://127.0.0.1:8000/:122
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>  http://127.0.0.1:8000/build/assets/app-63cee2c2.js:44

What may be the case and how to import this correctly?